# TypeScript & ...rest with Pick, Exclude, oh my

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'd like to be able to create the Props type of a React component, such that it has all properties of the "core" HTML element it renders, but allowing for my component to override some of those props. In a picture/code:

[image: illustration]

As you can see from the code-completion of `Combined`, it does the union of the `onChange` property, but I want it to be only `() => number` and not `FormEventHandler`.

How do I tell the TS compiler this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import { FormEventHandler } from 'react'
type Prop = { a: number; onChange: () => number }
type Other = { b: string; onChange: FormEventHandler }
type Combined = Prop & Omit<Other, keyof Prop>
function x(c: Combined) {
  return c.onChange() // => number
}
```

Comment: Found the answer just after posting the question.